# Issue with Core Data with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I have created a calendar app and I need to sync events across devices. I have searched and found this tutorial :
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-shopping-list-application-with-cloudkit-introduction--cms-24674

I have followed and setup iCloud in my app's capabilities :
[image]

Then setup this code:

```
private func fetchUserRecordID() {
    // Fetch Default Container
    let defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

    // Fetch User Record
    defaultContainer.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler { (recordID, error) -> Void in
        if let responseError = error {
            print(responseError)

        } else if let userRecordID = recordID {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.fetchUserRecord(userRecordID)
            })
        }
    }
}




private func fetchUserRecord(recordID: CKRecordID) {
    // Fetch Default Container
    let defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

    // Fetch Private Database
    let privateDatabase = defaultContainer.privateCloudDatabase

    // Fetch User Record
    privateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(recordID) { (record, error) -> Void in
        if let responseError = error {
            print(responseError)

        } else if let userRecord = record {
            print(userRecord)
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Fetch User Record ID
    fetchUserRecordID()
}
```

When the app runs the compiler gives me this output:

```
<CKRecord: 0x13f549090; recordType=Users, recordID=_3c16e121bd62445ae4f98b93c1488025:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=1>
```

I created an event on my iPhone then open the app on iPad but nothing happens.

This is my Core Data model :

[image]

Comment: CloudKit != iCloud.  iCloud/CoreData is deprecated so I would not recommend using it.  CloudKit is a separate framework.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra i am using Cloud Kit not iCloud !